# When using shapeless.Generic, how to avoid the error 'super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name'?

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

The following simple program cannot compile, under off-the-shelf scala 2.12 and shapeless 2.3.2:

```
import shapeless.Generic

object InferGeneric {

  class WithGeneric[T](implicit ev: Generic[T])

  case class Impl() {}

  object Impl extends WithGeneric[Impl]
}
```

The compiler throws the following error:

```
/.../InferGeneric.scala:11: super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name
  object Impl extends WithGeneric[Impl]
```

The interesting thing is that when `object Impl` is renamed it can compile without a problem. It appears that the macro used in Generic inference can cause some cyclic resolving when combining with companion object. How to avoid this situation?

Thanks a lot for your opinion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the macro-generated code, but it's not really macro-specific. You can reproduce the issue with an explicitly defined instance:

```
import shapeless._

class WithGeneric[T](implicit ev: Generic[T])

case class Impl()

object Impl extends WithGeneric[Impl]()(
  new Generic[Impl] {
    type Repr = HNil
    def to(p: Impl): Repr = HNil
    def from(p: Repr): Impl = Impl()
  }
)
```

Or if you want to make sure there are no macros involved:

```
trait Generic[A] { def mk: A }

class WithGeneric[T](ev: Generic[T])

case class Impl()

object Impl extends WithGeneric[Impl](
  new Generic[Impl] { def mk: Impl = Impl() }
)
```

In general you're not going to be able to pass code that calls `Impl.apply` in a constructor call when instantiating the `Impl` companion object.

It's hard to suggest a workaround without knowing more about what you're trying to do with `WithGeneric`. In simple cases like this you could define `Generic[Impl]` explicitly and only use the `new Impl` constructor (not `Impl.apply`). If what you want is to be able to provide companion object convenience methods with definitions that abstract over case classes, you could do something like this:

```
import shapeless._

abstract class WithGeneric[T] {
  def ev: Generic[T]
}

case class Impl()

object Impl extends WithGeneric[Impl] {
  def ev: Generic[Impl] = Generic[Impl]
}
```

It's a little boilerplate, but without knowing more about your use cases, my guess is that it's probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hope this syntax could be supported in the next version of compiler.